# Unable to access control from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am having the following code in my Xaml page of WPF project.

```
<Rectangle Name="myrect" MouseDown="myrect_MouseDown"/>
```

I have tried to set the fill property of the rectangle in code behind (i.e. in Xaml.cs)
but the name myrect is not accessible from code behind.. what is am missing here.?

I need to change the Fill property when particular rectangle is selected, any ways to achieve it through property binding or styles?

Thanks

Comment: Is that within some Template ?

Comment: If you want to access the control by name then you need to use the `x:Name` syntax (where `x` is defined `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"` in the UserControl/Page.

Comment: Can you show us the CodeBehind?

Comment: @user3610920, did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 3):

In mouse down event you have parameter `object sender`.
This is your `Rectangle`.

Something like that:

```
private void myrect_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var rect = sender as Rectangle;
    if(rect!=null)
     {

      //do it here...

     }

}
```